# How to know if linear regression model is working well?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science

I am working on a dataset about voting behavior. I have to run an OLS regression to estimate the impact of disagreement on abortion. This is my first time playing with the data. I have two dependent variables. I'm using scikit learn linear regression model.

After running the model I have got:
coefffieciet values: 0.118221, 0.330132

Actual value: 32105, 34157, 44165, 13890, 53047, 0.140918

Predicted values: 0.47105 , 1.037624, 0.471050, 0.919403

Mean Absolute Error: 0.5163281569302932

Mean Squared Error: 0.47136062479402246

Root Mean Squared Error: 0.6865570805068013

Idk if these values are correct. How to know if the values are correct? And if not correct what parameters should be change?

Following is my code:

```
X = df[['Deviation from Partisanship','Democrat']] 
Y = df['Disagreement with Party on Social Issues']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient']) 
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
df1.head()
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Comment: It looks like your predicted values aren't the same scale as your actual values

Comment: how to scale them?